# Eliminate outlier datapoints in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, outliers

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this reproducible code and I want to remove the outliers (in our case datapoints below or above 2.5 standard deviations above the mean) for each column without removing the entire subject/row.

```
Subj <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
Var1 <- c("1", "5", "100", "0.1", "3", "5", "2", "3", "2.5", "4")
Var2 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=TRUE)
Var3 <- runif(10, min=0, max=700)
Var4 <- c("0.5", "0.1", "23", "0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.12", "0.3", "0.25", "-75")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Subj, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4))

df$Var1_scale <- scale(as.numeric(df$Var1), scale = TRUE)
df$Var2_scale <- scale(as.numeric(df$Var2))
df$Var3_scale <- scale(as.numeric(df$Var3))
df$Var4_scale <- scale(as.numeric(df$Var4))
```

I would want to eliminate two datapoints - 100 for Var1 and -75 for Var4 based on the scaled variables. What is the best way of doing this? I always see it as eliminating the rows but that's not the aim here.

The output would look something like this (i.e. blank space instead of outlier)

```
   Subj Var1 Var2             Var3 Var4 Var1_scale Var2_scale Var3_scale Var4_scale
1     A    1    9 82.5652090134099  0.5 -0.3757658  0.8660254 -1.2116275  0.2128018
2     B    5    2 606.970524415374  0.1 -0.2457431 -1.1547005  1.2318109  0.1971919
3     C         9 422.833283618093   23  2.8422981  0.8660254  0.3738333  1.0908581
4     D  0.1   10 100.154890632257  0.2 -0.4050210  1.1547005 -1.1296693  0.2010944
5     E    3    4 144.251625519246  0.4 -0.3107545 -0.5773503 -0.9242029  0.2088993
6     F    5    2 310.489796195179  0.6 -0.2457431 -1.1547005 -0.1496251  0.2167043
7     G    2    8 624.485966027714 0.12 -0.3432602  0.5773503  1.3134231  0.1979724
8     H    3    3 617.240970185958  0.3 -0.3107545 -0.8660254  1.2796654  0.2049969
9     I  2.5   10 293.290452379733 0.25 -0.3270073  1.1547005 -0.2297645  0.2030456
10    J    4    3 223.737383470871      -0.2782488 -0.8660254 -0.5538433 -2.7335648
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing them with blank replace them with `NA` so that the classes are maintained.

```
cols <- paste0('Var', 1:4)
mat <- sapply(df[cols], function(x) {
  mn <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  sd <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  (x > mn + sd * 2.5) | (x < mn - sd * 2.5)
})
df[cols][mat] <- NA

df
#   Subj Var1 Var2      Var3  Var4
#1     A  1.0    2 383.35261  0.50
#2     B  5.0    8 498.22071  0.10
#3     C   NA    6 272.23357 23.00
#4     D  0.1    1  70.61119  0.20
#5     E  3.0    2 649.11146  0.40
#6     F  5.0    7 198.26275  0.60
#7     G  2.0    7 413.40121  0.12
#8     H  3.0    4  77.25242  0.30
#9     I  2.5    9 588.35492  0.25
#10    J  4.0    8 222.57458    NA
```

**data**

You have created dataset in a way which changes numbers to characters which makes it difficult to perform any mathematical calculation on them. I use `type.convert` to change them to their original classes.

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

Comment: Not sure why, but it does not work for me. Does not work for my data nor for the reproducible example. "mat" for me is just NA for everything.

Comment: If you are on R < 4.0.0 do 1) `df <- data.frame(Subj, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and 2) `df <- type.convert(df)` and try the answer again.

Comment: I do not know how to determine outliers, although base R has outlier function for you. ie `x<- boxplot(scale(df[-1)); x$out; x$group` where `x$out` are the outliers and `x$group` are the columns from which the outlierscame from. Base R uses the `fivenum` method.

Comment: @RonakShah What would you do if the dataframe is from an csv file, would you just do df <- data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)? Also, this bit "cols <- paste0('Var', 1:4)" does it automatically know which dataframe you are referring to? What should one do if columns have different names? would paste0(select(name:name)) work?

Comment: @CatM If you are reading data from csv file `df <- read.csv('csv_file_name.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` is enough. `cols` should have column names that you want to turn to `NA`. Here you have `Var1`, Var2` so I used a shortcut to generate it with `paste0`. If your actual column names are "abc", "efg" you should write `cols <- c("abc", "efg")`

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I was thinking if there was a way to abbreviate the number of columns as I want it to go through 8 of them and they all have different names.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you and that you are a genius!